Setting PHP.ini variables in Laragon Local Development Environment
I am using Laragon 6.0 on Windows 10 to set up and manage a local development environment for a Wordpress site.  The wordpress theme that I'm using requires a number of php environment variables to be set to the necessary values.  Specifically, the max_input_variables must be set to 5000.
Can anyone help explain how Laragon handles PHP configuration?
I have changed the configuration in the wp-admin folder php.ini file to the above, but when the site is up and running the theme detects that max_input_variables = 1000.  I can't seem to get it adjusted.  It must be overriden somehow in the Laragon environment.
I've included the wp-admin/php.ini file below for reference.
    ; cPanel-generated php ini directives, do not edit
    ; Manual editing of this file may result in unexpected behavior.
    ; To make changes to this file, use the cPanel MultiPHP INI Editor (Home >> Software >> MultiPHP INI    Editor)
    ; For more information, read our documentation (https://go.cpanel.net/EA4ModifyINI)

    allow_url_fopen = On
    allow_url_include = Off
    display_errors = Off
    enable_dl = Off
    file_uploads = On
    max_execution_time = 90000
    max_input_time = 90000
    max_input_vars = 5000
    memory_limit = 25600M
    post_max_size = 26000M
    session.gc_maxlifetime = 144000
    session.save_path = "/var/cpanel/php/sessions/ea-php70"
    upload_max_filesize = 25600M
    zlib.output_compression = Off``


From what I know about my little usage of Laragon, it does not handle the PHP configuration in a particular way. PHP does handle its config files on its own.
You should check which configuration files are loaded and the order they are loaded in with the following command:
php --ini

Maybe you have multiple config files, resulting in some conflicts on this specific parameter that you mentioned (max_input_variables).


In the Laragon interface, click on the Menu button (the three horizontal lines) located in the top-right corner.
Navigate to PHP > php.ini. This action will open the php.ini file in your default text editor.
Change the values in php.ini as required.
For the changes to take effect, you need to restart the web server. In the Laragon interface, click on the Menu button again, then go to Apache > Restart (or Nginx > Restart if you're using Nginx).


This actually did the trick!!   Thank you very much.  Appreciate the education.
